# Adding meta deltafetch_key for every request in SitemapSpider and CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm using scrapinghub's deltafetch feature in order to get new pages from a website, without requesting the urls I have already scraped.

I've noticed that on some websites, scrapy would still scrap pages with an already visited url. I had to replace the default fingerprint deltafetch_key, by just using the url.

It works fine with a scrapy `Spider`, since I can define the meta in the requests. However, when using `CrawlSpider` and `SitemapSpider`, I'm a bit stuck. For exemple, the `SitemapSpider`, has a `_parse_sitemap` method that includes `Requests`, but I can't really override it.

I've tried using a custom `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`, by using `process_request` and adding `request.meta['deltafetch_key'] = xxx`. But somehow the deltafetch spider middleware is getting called before the custom downloader middleware.

Do you have any ideas how to add `meta` informations to the `Request` of `CrawlSpider` and `SitemapSpider`?

Answer (score 0):

you can override  the original meta something like this

```
r.meta['original_meta'] = response.meta
```

i got this from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/704